# Paypal - Passing Multiple 'Custom' Variables

Tags: php, paypal

I have my website linked to Paypal. On my website, I pass information to PayPal as follows;

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@email.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">

        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $randomString ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/thank-you/">
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"> 

        <?php 
        if (($Adults > 0) && ($Students > 0) && ($Children > 0))
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Adult - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Adults . "'>";

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value='" . $selectroute ." (Student - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_2' value='" . $Students . "'>";

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_3' value='" . $selectroute ." (Child - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_3' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_3' value='" . $Children . "'>";
        }
        elseif (($Adults > 0) && ($Students > 0))
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Adult - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Adults . "'>";

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value='" . $selectroute ." (Student - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_2' value='" . $Students . "'>";
        }
        elseif (($Students > 0) && ($Children > 0))
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Student - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Students . "'>";

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value='" . $selectroute ." (Child - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_2' value='" . $Children . "'>";
        }
        elseif (($Adults > 0) && ($Children > 0))
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Adult - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Adults . "'>";

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value='" . $selectroute ." (Child - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_2' value='" . $Children . "'>";
        }
        elseif ($Adults > 0)
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Adult - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Adults . "'>";
        }
        elseif ($Students > 0)
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Student - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Students . "'>";
        }
        elseif ($Children > 0)
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Child - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Children . "'>";
        }
        ?>

        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_paynow_cc_144x47.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" style="position:relative; top: 8em; padding-left:45em;">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

After payment, the user is redirected back to the Thank You page on my website. On this page, I can use the information passed via PayPal in a confirmation email.

```
        $ItemName1 = $keyarray['item_name1'];
        $ItemName2 = $keyarray['item_name2'];
        $ItemName3 = $keyarray['item_name3'];
        $TotalCost = $keyarray['mc_gross'];
        $Quantity1 = $keyarray['quantity1'];
        $Quantity2 = $keyarray['quantity2'];
        $Quantity3 = $keyarray['quantity3'];
        $ItemCost1 = $keyarray['mc_gross_1'];
        $ItemCost2 = $keyarray['mc_gross_2'];
        $ItemCost3 = $keyarray['mc_gross_3'];
        $Currency = $keyarray['mc_currency'];
        $BookingReference = $keyarray['custom'];
        $FirstName = $keyarray['first_name'];
        $LastName = $keyarray['last_name'];
        $Email = $keyarray['payer_email'];
```

I have used the custom variable already and I believe I can only use this once - is this correct? But I need to pass 2 more variables containing the Departure Time and the Return Time - how would I pass these if I cannot use custom variable again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate them with a separator:

```
// PHP
concatenatedString = "value1:value2:value3";

// HTML
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo concatenatedString ?>"/>
```

Then when it comes back, you can split the values and assign them properly.